# How can I push multiple values from inputs in a form to an array of objects in mongoose.model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am making a list of bibliography entries using a form adding values to a mongoose.model but certain entries would require to have multiple authors.

To add an author I have added a js script assigned to a button to add inputs for the author's first name and second name but when I submit the form instead of creating multiple author objects in an array of objects defined in a schema it just pushes all the first name values and second name values into the same object.
How could I differentiate different authors while using the same inputs to add multiple author objects to the array of authors?

This is the Schema:

```
const BiblibliographySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: [{
    firstName: "String",
    secondName: "String"
  }],
  title: "String",
  publishInfo: {
    publisher: "String",
    location: "String"
  },
  date: "Number"
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Bibliography", BiblibliographySchema);
```

This is the form:

```
<form class="bibliography-form" action="/workspace/bibliography" method="POST">
  <div id="add-input">
    <input type="text" name="bibliography[author][firstName]" 
    placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="bibliography[author][secondName]" 
    placeholder="Second Name">
    <button id="add-name" type="button">+</button>
    <br>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the js script that adds input fields:

```
var button = document.getElementById("add-name");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var br = document.createElement('br');
  document.getElementById("add-input").appendChild(br);
  var input1 = document.createElement('input');
  var input2 = document.createElement('input');
  input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input1.setAttribute('name', 'bibliography[author][firstName]');
  input1.setAttribute('placeholder', 'First Name');
  input2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input2.setAttribute('name', 'bibliography[author][secondName]');
  input2.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Second Name');
  document.getElementById("add-input").appendChild(input1);
  document.getElementById("add-input").appendChild(input2);
  document.getElementById("add-input").appendChild(br);
});
```

And this is the create route:

```
app.post('/workspace/bibliography', function(req, res){
  Bibliography.create(req.body.bibliography, function(err, newEntry){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/workspace/bibliography');
    }
  });
});
```

This his how it is the bibliography entry is displayed on the page:

```
<div>
   <% bibliography.forEach(function(entry){ %>
        <form action="/workspace/bibliography/<%=entry._id%>? 
        _method=DELETE" method="POST">
    <p>
      <%= entry.author.secondName %>, <%= entry.author.firstName %>. 
      <i><%= entry.title %>. <%= entry.publishInfo.publisher %></i>, 
      <%= entry.publishInfo.location%>, <%= entry.date %>.
      <button class="delete-bibliography-entry">x</button>
    </p>
        </form>
   <% }); %>
</div>
```

I would like the output to look like this:

- secondName, firstName. secondName, firstName

but right now it looks like this:

- secondName, secondName. firstName, firstName

thank you for any help!!!

Comment: in the post method, try to `console.log(req.body.bibliography)` and post us the output.

Comment: { 'author.firstName': 'Roald',
  'author.secondName': 'Dahl',
  title: 'Tales Of the Unexpected',
  'publishInfo.publisher': 'Penguin',
  'publishInfo.location': 'UK',
  date: '1979' }

Comment: I also just realised that I seem to be referencing the model improperly in the <input> name property:                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                 { **'author.firstName**': 'Roald', **'author.secondName'**: 'Dahl', title: 'Tales Of the Unexpected', 'publishInfo.publisher': 'Penguin', 'publishInfo.location': 'UK', date: '1979' }

Comment: @dimitristseggenes fixed name attribute so the output of console.log(req.body.bibliography) is corrected `{ author: { firstName: 'Roald', secondName: 'Dahl' },
  title: 'Tales Of the Unexpected',
  publishInfo: { publisher: 'Penguin', location: 'UK' },
  date: '1979' }`

Comment: ok, is this the output even for multiple row inputs?

Comment: no sorry multiple inputs looks like this: `{ author:
   { firstName: [ 'Roald', 'Italo' ],
     secondName: [ 'Dahl', 'Calvino' ] },
  title: 'This is the book title',
  publishInfo:
   { publisher: 'this is the publisher',
     location: 'this is where it was published' },
  date: '2019' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this line

`<%= entry.author.secondName %>, <%= entry.author.firstName %>`.
with this

```
<% for(var i=0; i<entry.author.secondName.length; i++) {%>
   <%= entry.author.secondName[i] %>, <%= entry.author.firstName[i] %> /
<% } %>
```

**Updated**:
The way you post your data is the problem. It handles all your inputs as a single string, that's why it stores all `firstName` and `secondName` in one array element and not to many. The proper way to post an array of objects is  to make an AJAX request. Just for your case now, if you want to find a quick  solution, you could use only one input (e.g. `fullName`) and display the whole name.

Comment: Unfortunately _.length_ and _entry.author.secondName[i]_ are undefined and don't work getting error: **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Comment: Also the author array should look like this: `author: [{firstName: Roald, secondName: Dahl},{firstName: Italo, secondName: Calvino}]`

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. This is because you post data using html form method. The proper way is to use an AJAX request in order to post the whole data.